# Moving register values to memory variables in section data

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I need help moving a value from a register to memory but every time I run my code I get a seg fault. The goal is to assign M to J + K - 1.

```
section data:
    M dw 0
    J dw 3
    K dw 4

section text:

    global _start

    ; Show how this statement M= J+K -1 could be translated into assembly code using 8086 instruction set.
    ; Assume M, J and K are memory variables. In 8086 assume 16-bit, we can use MOV
    ; instruction to copy the variable into register ex: MOV AX, J.

    _start:
        mov bx, [K] ; move K into bx
        sub bx, 1 ; subtract 1 from bx
        mov ax, [J] ; move J into ax
        add ax, bx ; add J + (K - 1)
        mov [M], ax ; move ax value into M. This is where the seg fault occurs.

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

Comment: The code comments suggest this is suppose to be 16-bit code, but the syscall suggests you placed 64-bit code. Are you writing for 16-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: And M, J and K seem to be 32 bit values (dw).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: `dw` is 1 word wide; 32-bit is `dd`.  In x86 terminology, a "word" is 16 bits.  The code is correct except for the section names, just very weird (using 16-bit integers in 64-bit mode, with `[disp32]` absolute addressing modes because it omits `default rel`).  Also inefficient because it doesn't use `[J]` as a memory source operand for `add`..

Comment: @PeterCordes: `<facepalm>`. I actually know this. My defense: I hadn't had any coffee yet. <g>

Answer (score 2):

The linker doesn't know about sections called `data:` or `text:`, they're just random custom section names and you didn't set permission (read/write/execute) for them.  (Use `:` after labels, not section names)

**You want `section .data` and `section .text`**

(Also, I'd recommend `default rel` because you want NASM to use RIP-relative addressing for addresses like `[K]`.)

---

After building a static executable with `nasm -felf64 foo.asm && ld -o foo foo.o` on my Arch Linux desktop,

```
$ readelf -a foo
...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000
                 0x0000000000000031 0x0000000000000031  R      0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     data: text: 

...
```

So we can see that the `text:` and `data:` sections were both linked a read-only non-executable program segment, so code-fetch for the first instruction of `_start` will fault.  Or at least you'd expect it would, but single-stepping under GDB it didn't segfault until it tried to store back to memory, and that faulted because it *is* mapped read-only.

And yes, that the `:` at the end of the section names did actually appear in the object file.